# Remove Friends hackerearth: Runtime Error - NZEC :IndexError: deque index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

Problem Statement (https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/remove-friends-5)

I am stuck on this problem. Kindly point out what is wrong and what can be done in order to get the correct output.

Thankyou for help

After getting her PhD, Christie has become a celebrity at her university, and her facebook profile is full of friend requests. Being the nice girl she is, Christie has accepted all the requests.

Now Kuldeep is jealous of all the attention she is getting from other guys, so he asks her to delete some of the guys from her friend list. To avoid a 'scene', Christie decides to remove some friends from her friend list, since she knows the popularity of each of the friend she has, she uses the following algorithm to delete a friend.

Algorithm Delete(Friend):

```
         DeleteFriend=false

 for i = 1 to Friend.length-1

 if (Friend[i].popularity < Friend[i+1].popularity)

    delete i th friend

    DeleteFriend=true

    break
if(DeleteFriend == false)

delete the last friend
```

Input: First line contains T number of test cases. First line of each test case contains N, the number of friends Christie currently has and K ,the number of friends Christie decides to delete. Next lines contains popularity of her friends separated by space.

Output: For each test case print N-K numbers which represent popularity of Christie friend's after deleting K friends.

NOTE Order of friends after deleting exactly K friends should be maintained as given in input.

SAMPLE INPUT:

3

3 1

3 100 1

5 2

19 12 3 4 17

5 3

23 45 11 77 18

SAMPLE OUTPUT

100 1

19 12 17

77 18

MY SOLUTION:

```
import collections as col

def delete(n, k, frnd):

    temp = []

    while k!=0:   

        for f in frnd:

            if f<f+1:

                del frnd[f]

                k -= 1

    temp.append(frnd)

print(" ".join(map(str, temp))) 

for i in range(int(input())):

  n, k = (map(int, input().split()))

  frnd = col.deque(list(map(int, input().split())))

  delete(n, k, frnd)
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question, as it stands, is not sutable yet. In particular, it lacks required info, which must be inline (not a link!). Further, pay attention to the fact that you are not even asking a question! You're just asking for general help and assistance. Please come back when you have encountered an actual problem. Be specific about that problem. Take care with the formatting (even more so with Python code!).

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error use replace your `for` loop to

```
for idx, f in enumerate(frnd):
    if f<f+1:
        del frnd[idx]
        break # <------
```

You were getting the error because you were using the value instead of the index to delete the entry in the `deque`

Comment: upon updating the for loop as per your suggestion i get an error:            
RuntimeError : deque mutated during iteration

Comment: you need to break after `del`

Comment: if i insert break after del frnd[indx] i get : Time Limit Exceeded                                        
 .....                                                                                                                              
 if i insert break  after k-=1 then i get :                                                  deque([100, 1])
deque([3, 4, 17]) deque([3, 4, 17])
deque([77, 18]) deque([77, 18]) deque([77, 18])